# How can I get the variables of a file 'Index.php' that included 'Init.php', without reincluding 'Init.php'?

Tags: php, variables, include

I am currently working on some upgrades of a small personal framework that uses MVC.

The way it works currently is that when Init.php is included in a certain file, instead of looking for a variable, it gets the text content of the file (The actual source code) and just "cuts out" the variables. I believe it's heavily unorthodox and honestly, just bad.

A fellow developer also worked on a framework that also used MVC and was able to do what I was wanting to do the correct way.

```
<?php

require 'Init.php';

$page['id'] = 'index';
$page['name'] = 'Home';
```

That's what both of our files look like, however, if I was to let's say, use a variable instead of a string on the $page['name'] element, the title of the page would literally be the variable name (Imagine "Sitename - $variable")

I've been for about 2 days looking for an answer, and I found one promising one that was basically using require_once and ob_get_contents, however, I do not wish to use require_once.

How could I do what my fellow developer has done?

**Edit**
Here's my current attempt at getting the array, it only works when using require_once.

```
/************* CONTENT PARSING **************/

global $page;

$buffer = explode('/', $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
$filename = $buffer[count($buffer) - 1]; // index.php in our case

var_dump($page); // Dumps NULL

ob_start();

include($filename);

echo $page['id']; // Echoes nothing

echo ob_get_contents(); // Echoes nothing

echo $page['id']; // Dumps nothing

ob_flush(); // Returns nothing

var_dump($page); // Dumps nothing
```

**EDIT 2**
Here's the way files are included and variables are declared

`config.php` and `pageTpl.php` are included in `Init.php`

`config.php` contains the `$page` array and is included before `pageTpl.php`

`index.php` includes `Init.php`

In a few words, the value that I want to assign to the `id` and `name` element of the `$page` array can only be accessed if you're on `index.php`, I would like it for the developer to access the variable globally. (Where Init.php is included)

I attempted to run a `var_extract($page)` on each of those files and the results were as follows:

config.php (Where the `$page` array is declared):
`array ( 'id' => '', 'name' => '', ),`
Init.php (Where `config.php` is included):
`array ( 'id' => '', 'name' => '', ),`
index.php (Where the values are changed):
`array ( 'id' => 'index', 'name' => 'Test', )`
pageTpl.php (File included in `Init.php`, attempts to access the `$page` array):
`NULL`

Comment: Are you by chance using ticks around your variable name?  Something like this? `$page['id'] = '$variable';`  If so, remove the ticks.

Comment: As a note about the above comment: PHP does not evaluate variables in strings enclosed in single quotes: `'this is my $value'` does not work as `"this is my $value"` or `'this is my ' . $value`.

Comment: Why would you not use require_once? I exclusively use require_once.

Comment: Well the variable issue was just an example, the point is that, for Init.php, the $page array is undefined. I have however removed the ticks and it hasn't made any difference.

Comment: @KevinNagurski I don't use require_once because I will be distributing the framework to other fellow developers and I don't want them to have to debug my errors, a lot of people are a lot more comfortable using require or include.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow - http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php  As long as `$variable` is defined in global scope within `Init.php`, then `$page['name'] = "Sitename - $variable";` will work successfully, not resulting in the text but in the substitution. Could you edit your post and include code from `Init.php`

Comment: @CristianHG I'm a little confused. require_once does exactly what require does but just makes sure it only does it once. Unless you want the file to be able to be required multiple times, require_once is a better choice

Comment: @Twisty I have added my current attempt

Comment: @KevinNagurski I agree with that, however, because this will be distributed to other developers, I want to make sure that they are able to use whatever method of inclusion they desire to use.

Comment: Did you check if `include` actually succeeded? maybe you're requesting `init.php`, which will fail on a case-sensitive file system.

Comment: You never explain where `$page` gets defined.

Comment: @Twisty Sorry, I thought I'd put the definition in the sample. At the very beginning of the file I define `$page` as `$page = array()`

Comment: @MarcB I have already verified that both files were included successfully.

Comment: Based on the new info, this seems to be expected behavior. You define `$page` but don't add any values to it until `index.php`. Please explain what your end goal is, it's not clear. "I would like it for the developer to access the variable globally. (Where Init.php is included)" To do this, you need to define and assign values in `Init.php`. Then the values are available to all other pages.

Comment: You're correct Twisty, however, as I said before, a fellow developer of mine has been able to achieve this using PHP and therefore I believe there must an efficient, ethical way to imitate his result.

Comment: My goal is basically to be able to access the new value of $page from any file that included Init.php, so if I change $page['id'] on index.php I want to be able to access that newly updated value on whatever file included Init.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so after going around the documentation a few times and reading over the code of a few frameworks I noticed that the only way to get the final value of all those variables was using the PHP `register_shutdown_function` that is the function that is called after script execution finishes, this means that all variables are processed, calculated and can therefore all be accessed from that function as long as they are global.

Example:

**index.php**

```
<?

require 'Init.php';

$page['id'] = 'index';
$page['name'] = 'Home';
```

Then, on Init.php we do all the complicated frameworky-stuff, but we also include the kernel, that will contain the shutdown function

**Init.php**

```
<?

require 'inc/kernel.php';

new Kernel;
```

Now, the kernel, of course

**kernel.php**

```
<?

class Kernel
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        register_shutdown_function('Kernel::Shutdown'); // Registers shutdown callback
        spl_autoload_register('Kernel::LoadMod'); // Not exactly sure why is this function necessary, but it is. All I know is that it tries to files of called classes that weren't included
    }

    static function Shutdown()
    {
        global $page;

        var_dump($page); // Will print what we defined in the $page array

        Module::LoadTpl($page); // We pass the $page array to the tpl module that will do the rest
    }
}
```

**module.php**

class Module
{
    static function LoadTpl($page)
    {
        var_dump($page); // Will also print $page, but now we're not confined to kernel.php
    }
}

Then, from the `Module` class you can pass the `$page` array to other classes/files.

Comment: `$page = array('id', 'name');` won't do what you want there. Try `$page = array('id' => 0, 'name' = "");`. Or simply: `$page = array();` and define the indexes later.

Answer (score -1):

When you define an array, with indexes, you need to do it in a specific way.

config.php:

```
<?php 
$page = array('id' => "", 'name' => "");
var_export($page);
?>
```

This will create array called `$page`, with an index of `id` & `name` that have values of nothing.

Now in your index.php, you can assign values:

```
<html>
<body>
<pre>
<?php

include 'Init.php';

$page['id'] = basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
$page['name'] = 'Home';

var_export($page);
?>
</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

This should result in a page that shows:

```
array ( 'id' => '', 'name' => '', )
array ( 'id' => 'index.php', 'name' => 'Home', )
```

Comment: I'm very sorry for my answer, it appears I looked at it too quick and thought I fixed it. I have tried this but the value of the element still does not change.

Comment: When you add `var_export($page);` to each of the pages, what results are you getting?

Comment: On `config.php` it returns `array ( 'id' => '', 'name' => '', )`, on `Init.php` it returns `array ( 'id' => '', 'name' => '', )`, on `index.php` it returns `array ( 'id' => 'index', 'name' => 'Test', )` and on pageTpl.php it just returns `NULL`. **TL;DR** The new values are still confined to index.php

Comment: Ok, something is missing in your explanation. Are you including `pageTpl.php` in `index.php`?

Comment: No, pageTpl.php is included in Init.php

Comment: And is anything added to $page before `pageTpl.php` is included? Please edit your original post and add all the new details to this issue.